# Rails - batch sql query - Primary key not included in the custom select clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a legacy database with multiple existing tables, I want to query thousands of records in one legacy table that **doesn't have primary key**

```
   LegacyTable.where(condition, start_date, end_date).find_each do |record|
      yield record
    end
```

but it will throw the bellow error:

```
ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier
```

because it auto generates `order by "LegacyTable".""`
according to the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)

> NOTE: It's not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work. This also means that this method only works with integer-based primary keys.

Then I set `self.primary_key = 'TRANSACTION_ID'` in the model, but TRANSACTION_ID is just an index in legacy table. Then it throws another exception:

```
RuntimeError (Primary key not included in the custom select clause):
```

How to do batch query in rails? If use Java, I can just add fetchSize parameter and don't need primary key in table.

Answer (score 3):

ActiveRecord's `find_in_batches` (which `find_each` based on) is relying on primary key ordering to perform batches extraction in multiple queries ([details](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches)). As *@aliibrahim* have already mentioned, you have to implement pagination on your own.

While I'm aware the question is about Oracle, for others coming from Google it worths mentioning, there is a great solution to the problem for those using PostgreSQL: [postgresql_cursor](https://rubygems.org/gems/postgresql_cursor) gem.

> PostgreSQL Cursor is an extension to the ActiveRecord PostgreSQLAdapter for very large result sets. It provides a cursor open/fetch/close interface to access data without loading all rows into memory, and instead loads the result rows in "chunks" (default of 1_000 rows), buffers them, and returns the rows one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Legacy.where` (meaning not using as ORM, which tries to map each row to a model record) its advisable to just use this as connector to DB and do a query like `Legacy.find_by_sql`

Comment: Does `find_by_sql` support fetch size or batch size?, It have to avoid load all records into memory.

Comment: You should mention batch size (or limit) within the query itself.

Comment: You mean that I should implement the underlying logic that find_each did? I want to get all records without limit size, e.g. one query only fetch 1000 records, then use the same query to fetch the rest until I get all the records